# TypeError : 'type' object does not support item assignment

Tags: python, python-3.x, email, sendmail, smtplib

```
def send_email():

 sender = "example@gmail.com"
 password = "wefqffefw"

 server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
 server.starttls()

 try:
     server.login(sender, password)
     msg = MIMEMultipart
     msg["From"] = sender
     msg["To"] = sender
     msg["Subject"] = "отправка файла"

     for file in os.listdir("attachments"):
         print(file)

     with open("data.csv") as f:
         file = MIMEText(f.read())

     file.add_header('content-disposition', 'attachment', filename='data')
     msg.attach(file)
     server.sendmail(sender, sender, msg.as_string())

     return "The message was sen successfully!"
 except Exception as _ex:
     return f"{_ex}\nCheck your login or password!"

def main():
 print(send_email())

if __name__ == '__main__':
 main()
```

Comment: Переведи на русский.

Comment: `TypeError : 'type' object does not support item assignment` - в какой строке? Приведите полный текст ошибки вместе со стектрейсом.

Comment: `msg = MIMEMultipart` тут не было создания объекта

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка тут:

```py
     msg = MIMEMultipart
     msg["From"] = sender
```

`MIMEMultipart` - это класс. Видимо, пропущены скобки, класс нужно инстанциировать, а вы просто присвоили переменной `msg` ссылку на этот класс.

Видимо, правильно будет так:

```py
     msg = MIMEMultipart()
     msg["From"] = sender
```